# Does iOS give permission to turn on or turn off cellular data within an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-today-widget, cellular-network

For example, is it possible to make a widget so that I can turn off cellular data in the Today Widgets?

Without jailbreaking, does iOS give the permission to turn on cellular data?

Comment: Tagged with *jailbreak*, really?

Comment: @LinusG. i removed it. @ user Dont include tags that your post is explicitly NOT about.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at a device level. However you can configure your application to not use cellular data.

There is no programmatic interface to disable cellular data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually try to achieve: Do you want to turn off the use of cellular data for the whole phone, or do you just access a URL without possibly making it costly for the user because of cellular data?

For the latter, that's an option that you can set before each individual download.

Comment: I'm trying to make an app which can control the cellular data for the whole device, like a cellular data switch.